# How to stop page from scrolling while displaying an image sequence?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an apple-style page where there's a canvas displaying an image sequence on scroll, but that scrolling doesn't move the page until the last image of the sequence. How can I do this? This is what I've got.

html:

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="image-hero"></canvas>
    <h1 class="centered title" style="font-size: 4rem;">Test Text</h1>
</body>
```

js:

```js
const html = document.documentElement; 
const canvas = document.getElementById('image-hero');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const frameCount = 148;
const currentFrame = index => ( `https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg` )
   
const preloadImages = () => {
   for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = currentFrame(i);
   }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width = 1158;
canvas.height = 770;
img.onload = function() { context.drawImage(img, 0, 0); }

const updateImage = index => {
   img.src = currentFrame(index);
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   //don't scroll the page until the animation is done
   

   const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
   const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
   const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
   const frameIndex = Math.min(
      frameCount - 1,
      Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
   );
   
   requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});
preloadImages()

disableScrolling();
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way imo would be to make the positioned fixed, so that when you scroll the canvas itself will stay in the same play, so the content on it won't move.

You can set this directly in the HTML like

```
canvas id="image-hero" style="position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 0px" ></canvas>
```

This should make it so that the canvas is positioned at 100px from the top and 0px from the left, and doesn't move when the page is scrolled.

alternatively, you can change the attributed from the JS so that you can control when you want to make the canvas scroll and not scroll

```
let el = document.getElementById("image-hero");
el.style.position = "fixed"; // this will make the canvas not move
el.style.position = "relative"; // this will make the canvas reset to scrolling with the page
```

hope this helps